# How to remove invalid characters from a string?

Tags: java, android

I have no idea how to remove invalid characters from a string in Java. I'm trying to remove all the characters that are not numbers, letters, or ( ) [ ] . How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
String foo = "this is a thing with & in it";
foo = foo.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9()\\[\\]]", "");
```

Javadocs are your friend. Regular expressions are also your friend.

**Edit:**

That being siad, this is only for the Latin alphabet; you can adjust accordingly. `\\w` can be used for `a-zA-Z` to denote a "word" character if that works for your case though it includes `_`.

Comment: The primary Java regexp reference: [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 8):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), and almost certainly more efficient (and more readable) than regexes:

```
CharMatcher desired = CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT
  .or(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER)
  .or(CharMatcher.anyOf("()[]"))
  .precomputed(); // optional, may improve performance, YMMV
return desired.retainFrom(string);
```

Comment: No need to be snippy.  It's a Java library, nothing more, and a handy one at that.

Comment: That's not how you use CharMatcher.or(), it only takes one argument

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String s = "123abc&^%[]()";
s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9()\\[\\]]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

The above will remove characters `"&^%"` in the sample string, leaving in `s` only `"123abc[]()"`.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "numbers", "letters" and so on. I certainly wouldn't expect `Straße` be changed to `Strae`. Heck I'd say it's a pretty `naïve`.. sorry `nave` solution ;)

Comment: just as an FYI, you don't have to escape the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String c = "hjdg$h&jk8^i0ssh6+/?:().,+-#";
    System.out.println(c);
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9/?:().,'+/-]");
    Matcher match = pt.matcher(c);
    if (!match.matches()) {
        c = c.replaceAll(pt.pattern(), "");
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: You should try to explain your answer a little bit, only posting a code snippet is not a good answer for people looking for help

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
String s = "Test[]"
s = s.replaceAll("[");
s = s.replaceAll("]");
```

Answer (score 0):

`myString.replaceAll("[^\\w\\[\\]\\(\\)]", "");`
replaceAll method takes a regex as first parameter and replaces all matches in string. This regex matches all characters which are not digit, letter or underscore (`\\w`) and braces you need (`\\[\\]\\(\\)]`)

Comment: Using `\w` won't do, since it includes the `_` character - an invalid character according to the question.

Comment: maybe he just forgot about underscore?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez - not in my Java and locale it doesn't.

Comment: @BrianRoach Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): `\w A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Comment: nm, I'm being retarded :-D Afternoon beer setting in, me thinks

Comment: It doesn't matches the `(` and `)` symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can remove specials characters from your String/Url or any request   parameters you have get from user side

```
  public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String inputString){
        final String[] metaCharacters = {"../","\\..","\\~","~/","~"};
        String outputString="";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < metaCharacters.length ; i++){
            if(inputString.contains(metaCharacters[i])){
                outputString = inputString.replace(metaCharacters[i],"");
                inputString = outputString;
            }else{
                outputString = inputString;
            }
        }
        return outputString;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the range of characters to keep/remove based on the order of characters in the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/). The regex can use actual characters or character hex codes:

```
// Example - remove characters outside of the range of "space to tilde".
// 1) using characters
someString.replaceAll("[^ -~]", "");

// 2) using hex codes for "space" and "tilde"
someString.replaceAll("[^\\u0020-\\u007E]", "");
```