# Android - How to filter unstoreable characters from a string?

Tags: android, emoji

I want to detect and remove unstoreable characters. For example some emojis are replaced by android with this -> �. But I can't save that so i have to remove it.

There was a similiar question ([How to filter emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178349/android-how-to-filter-emoji-emoticons-from-a-string)), but I don't want to forbid to write and save emojis.
And I think to use some of these ([How to remove invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144186/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-a-string)) is also not the best way, because I want to allow everything except �.

.contains("�") doesn't work and also .replace() and charAt(). So is there even a way?

Comment: Try getting the particular Unicode value for the emoji and use it to pick your emoji.

Comment: That is an idea, but what if the emoji isn't replaced at HTC but at LG. And also the other way. When I get the String from the EditText they are already replaced.

Comment: AFAIK unless the emoji is vendor specific, generally it should work. You can however code for all possibilities.

Comment: `this -> �. But I can't save that `. Why not? If they are in a String you can save the string.

Comment: the xml-parser i am using just saves an empty string if they are in it. I could maybe use another parser but then I have to change so much.