# Escaping a long sequence of metacharacters in the Java .replaceAll method

Tags: java, regex, escaping, replaceall, metacharacters

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now, I am using .replaceAll to remove any character in a String that is not a letter or number.  I tried using Pattern.quote(), but I was unable to make it work correctly.  Then I tried using \Q and \E, but it still isn't working, even with my frustrated attempts at varying numbers of backslashes.  This is my first time trying to escape in this manner so any help would really be appreciated.

Here is the line in question:

```
return input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\Q !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]\^_`~{}|\\E","");
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple fix here would be to just put all special characters inside a character class:

```
String input = "abc%#$123";
input = input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?@\\[\\]\\\\^_`~{}|]","");
System.out.println(input);

abc123
```

The character class admits most of your special characters as unescaped literals.  Exceptions are double quotes, backslash, and opening/closing square brackets, which however still do require escaping.

### Demo

Note: It might be much easier to just remove anything which is not alphanumeric, e.g.

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

But perhaps there are characters which the above would exclude but you really want to keep.

Comment: `,-.` need escaping.

Comment: @Pshemo [No they don't](http://rextester.com/ZYY53154), except for dash, which as you have pointed out should be moved to the very end of the character class.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: To be nitty-picky, the very start would work as well.

Comment: OK actually `,-.` is specifying range which matches only `,` `-` and `.` so this will work (by luck). But still to make regex easier to work with we should escape `-` when we mean it to be literal and not range indicator.

Comment: @Pshemo Good call...never actually thought of escaping dash in this way.  Most stuff you find on SO suggest just moving it to the end.

Comment: Putting the `-` at the end (or the start) without escaping feels dangerous: somebody might come along and add more characters after (or before). Saving two backslashes feels like false economy.

Answer (score 0):

return input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9()\[\]]", "");

Source: [How to remove invalid characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144186/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-a-string?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Hands off my  and.

 This removes far more than OP's code

Comment: @AndyTurner Whoa!  Where did those icons come from?  And doesn't soda go with pizza, rather than beer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they're just regular unicode emoji: [](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f355/index.htm), [](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f37a/index.htm).