# Remove non printable character from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string as below:

```
String s = "$$$$A very beautiful girl having loads of £££££ in her 20�s.";
```

I went through some StackOverflow responses and tried below:

```
s.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", " ");

s.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", " ");
```

Both of them are removing the wierd question mark , but they are also removing the pound(£) sign retaining the dollar($) sign.  I need to retain the currency symbol. Can you suggest a more suitable approach?

Also, is there any other library to do this rather than using the regex?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144186/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-a-string

Comment: � is an indicator to our users that we have mishandled their text and lost some it. Are you sure you don't want them to know? Can you go back upstream to before the text is being mishandled and use the correct character encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
s.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\xFF]", " ");
```

Your problem is, pound sign is a part of `Latin-1 Supplement` Unicode block, which is not included when you filter upto `7F`.

Answer (score 2):

To efficiently remove all unprintable characters from a string, including the often-overlooked Unicode control codes that have been exploited by hackers:

```
    String broken = "\r\nhello world\b\u200E\uDB80";

    StringBuilder fixed = broken.codePoints()
        .filter(c -> {
          switch (Character.getType(c)) {
            case Character.CONTROL:
            case Character.FORMAT:
            case Character.PRIVATE_USE:
            case Character.SURROGATE:
            case Character.UNASSIGNED:
              return false;
            default:
              return true;
          }
        })
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);

    assertEquals("hello world", fixed.toString());
```

If you want to remove other character classes then simply include them in the case statement. This implements a *blacklist*. If you prefer a *whitelist* then you can invert the logic to return `true` when a character is an acceptable type and return `false` for all others.